python coding I cant figure out the bottom code for the diamond and no other answers on here, must be coded this form
So now I have this and the bottom part is still all messed up please help
for a1 in range(1,30):
    for a3 in range (29-a1, 0, -1):
        print(" ", end ='')

    for a2 in range(1,a1+1):
        print("*", end=' ')

    print()

for a1 in range(28, 0, -1):
    for a3 in range (29-a1, 0, -1):
        print(" ", end ='')

    for a2 in range(1,a1+1):
        print("*", end=' ')


Change the second for a1 in range(1, 30): to be for a1 in range(28, 0, -1):, i.e. count down from 28, and you're set.
See the documentation for range() to see how that works, exactly.
An alternate, neat, short way to solve this could be to compute the half-diamond list with a list comprehension, then print it, and again in reverse:
star_lines = [" ".join("*" * x).center(59) for x in range(1, 30)]
print(*star_lines, sep="\n")
print(*star_lines[-2::-1], sep="\n")


I did that and it works but when I have the top part of the diamond and add that it messes it all up. I have no idea what Im doing wrong lol
